# Nodejs Mongoose - TypeError: Invalid sort() argument

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Hi I am trying to run my program, but when I try to connect to localhost in my browser I get the following error each time. I assume it's something wrong with my sorting or querying but I'm not really sure where exactly it's going wrong. Can anyone help fix my code? Is the app.js code correct as well, I feel there may be an error there too..? Any help welcome! :)

```
Express
500 TypeError: Invalid sort() argument. Must be a string or object.
at Query.sort (C:\nodeapps\nodeblox\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:1167:11)
at Function.Post.statics.getAll (C:\nodeapps\nodeblox\schemas\Post.js:44:9)
at module.exports.app.post.username (C:\nodeapps\nodeblox\routes\index.js:45:10)
at callbacks (C:\nodeapps\nodeblox\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:160:37)
at param (C:\nodeapps\nodeblox\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:134:11)
at pass (C:\nodeapps\nodeblox\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:141:5)
at Router._dispatch (C:\nodeapps\nodeblox\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:169:5)
at Object.router (C:\nodeapps\nodeblox\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:32:10)
at next (C:\nodeapps\nodeblox\node_modules\express\node_modules\connect\lib\proto.js:190:15)
at Object.methodOverride [as handle] (C:\nodeapps\nodeblox\node_modules\express\node_modules\connect\lib\middleware\methodOverride.js:37:5)
```

Post.js

```
'use strict';

var util = require('util');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var validatePresenceOf = function(value){
  return value && value.length; 
};

var toLower = function(string){
  return string.toLowerCase();
};

var getId = function(){
  return new Date().getTime();
};

/**
  * The Post schema. we will use timestamp as the unique key for each post
  */
var Post = new Schema({
  'key' : {
    unique : true,
    type : Number,
    default: getId
  },
  'subject' : { type : String,
                validate : [validatePresenceOf, 'Subject is Required']
              },
  'content' : {type : String},
  'author': String,
  'tags' : {
            type : String,
            set : toLower
           }
});

/**
  * Get complete post details for all the posts
  */
Post.statics.getAll = function(cb){
  var query = this.find({});
  query.sort('key', -1);
  return query.exec(cb);
};

/**
  * Get only the meta information of all the posts.
  */
Post.statics.getAllMeta = function(cb){
  return this.find({}, ['key','subject', 'author', 'tags'], cb);
};

Post.statics.findByKey = function(key, cb){
  return this.find({'key' : key}, cb);
};

module.exports = mongoose.model('Post', Post);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are most likely using a newer version of mongoose than your code was written for. The `.sort()` method has been updated and it now takes parameters like this, for descending order:

`query.sort('-key');`

Or you can use this version:

`query.sort({key: -1});`

Whichever you use, yours is outdated. See the [latest docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-sort).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, took some digging to find the new way to .sort so thanks.

Comment: If you're using TypeScript & Mongoose 8, `.sort({ xx: Number("-1") as SortOrder }))` will work - new changes mean that a) sort order cannot be a string and 2) cast sort order to `import {SortOrder} from 'mongoose';` when it's a number